# Check if value already exists within list of dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, search, key

I've got a Python list of dictionaries as follows:

```py
a = [
    {'main_color': 'red', 'second_color':'blue'},
    {'main_color': 'yellow', 'second_color':'green'},
    {'main_color': 'yellow', 'second_color':'blue'},
]
```

I'd like to check whether a dictionary with a particular key/value already exists in the list as follows:

```
// is a dict with 'main_color'='red' in the list already?
// if not: add item
```

Answer (score 418, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
if not any(d['main_color'] == 'red' for d in a):
    # does not exist
```

The part in parentheses is a generator expression that returns `True` for each dictionary that has the key-value pair you are looking for, otherwise `False`.

---

If the key could also be missing the above code can give you a `KeyError`. You can fix this by using `get` and providing a default value. If you don't provide a *default* value, `None` is returned.

```
if not any(d.get('main_color', default_value) == 'red' for d in a):
    # does not exist
```

Comment: Amazing one-liner syntax, I have been look so hard for this! I am curious that where in the Python docs that shows us we can actually put the operation of 'for' before the 'for' ?

Comment: I found it, it's called List Comprehensions https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.0.html?highlight=comprehensions

Comment: Is there a possibility to test if `'main_color': 'red'` AND `'second_color':'blue'` exist ?

Comment: Is there a way, once the expression has evaluated to true or false, to perform an action on the value without having to loop again?

Comment: its not working when data comes with "null" [{"main_color":null,"second_color":"red"}, {"main_color:"green","second_color":"null"}]

Comment: @Bryce If it's not that many elements, you could do something like `matchingElements = [d for d in a if d.get('main_color', default_value) == 'red']; if (len(matchingElements)): doSomething(matchingElements[0])`

Comment: If it happens inside an iteration wouldn't it be inefficient? And a better way would be to first create a data type with all the values and then check without iteration if the value is there, instead of iteration for every iteration

Answer (score 8):

Maybe this helps:

```
a = [{ 'main_color': 'red', 'second_color':'blue'},
     { 'main_color': 'yellow', 'second_color':'green'},
     { 'main_color': 'yellow', 'second_color':'blue'}]

def in_dictlist(key, value, my_dictlist):
    for entry in my_dictlist:
        if entry[key] == value:
            return entry
    return {}

print in_dictlist('main_color','red', a)
print in_dictlist('main_color','pink', a)
```

Comment: Update for Simplicity. However py3 doesnt like the extra parenthese

Answer (score 8):

Based on @Mark Byers great answer, and following @Florent question,
just to indicate that it will also work with 2 conditions on list of dics with more than 2 keys:

```
names = []
names.append({'first': 'Nil', 'last': 'Elliot', 'suffix': 'III'})
names.append({'first': 'Max', 'last': 'Sam', 'suffix': 'IX'})
names.append({'first': 'Anthony', 'last': 'Mark', 'suffix': 'IX'})

if not any(d['first'] == 'Anthony' and d['last'] == 'Mark' for d in names):

    print('Not exists!')
else:
    print('Exists!')
```

Result:

```
Exists!
```

Answer (score 5):

Just another way to do what the OP asked:

```py
 if not filter(lambda d: d['main_color'] == 'red', a):
     print('Item does not exist')
```

`filter` would filter down the list to the item that OP is testing for. The `if` condition then asks the question, "If this item is not there" then execute this block.

Comment: I think this needs to be `if not list(filter(lambda d: d['main_color'] == 'red', a)):` to create a list object which the if then tests if it's empty or not. `filter(..)` as above creates a filter object which will always be true.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps a function along these lines is what you're after:

```
 def add_unique_to_dict_list(dict_list, key, value):
  for d in dict_list:
     if key in d:
        return d[key]

  dict_list.append({ key: value })
  return value
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a check if the key exists would be a bit better, as some commenters asked under the preferred answer [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3897516/9620269)

So, I would add a small if clause at the end of the line:

```py
input_key = 'main_color'
input_value = 'red'

if not any(_dict[input_key] == input_value for _dict in a if input_key in _dict):
    print("not exist")
```

I'm not sure, if wrong but I think the OP asked to check, if the key-value pair exists and if not the key value pair should be added.

In this case, I would suggest a small function:

```py
a = [{ 'main_color': 'red', 'second_color': 'blue'},
     { 'main_color': 'yellow', 'second_color': 'green'},
     { 'main_color': 'yellow', 'second_color': 'blue'}]

b = None

c = [{'second_color': 'blue'},
     {'second_color': 'green'}]

c = [{'main_color': 'yellow', 'second_color': 'blue'},
     {},
     {'second_color': 'green'},
     {}]


def in_dictlist(_key: str, _value :str, _dict_list = None):
    if _dict_list is None:
        # Initialize a new empty list
        # Because Input is None
        # And set the key value pair
        _dict_list = [{_key: _value}]
        return _dict_list

    # Check for keys in list
    for entry in _dict_list:
        # check if key with value exists
        if _key in entry and entry[_key] == _value:
            # if the pair exits continue
            continue
        else:
            # if not exists add the pair
            entry[_key] = _value
    return _dict_list


_a = in_dictlist("main_color", "red", a )
print(f"{_a=}")
_b = in_dictlist("main_color", "red", b )
print(f"{_b=}")
_c = in_dictlist("main_color", "red", c )
print(f"{_c=}")
```

Output:

```
_a=[{'main_color': 'red', 'second_color': 'blue'}, {'main_color': 'red', 'second_color': 'green'}, {'main_color': 'red', 'second_color': 'blue'}]
_b=[{'main_color': 'red'}]
_c=[{'main_color': 'red', 'second_color': 'blue'}, {'main_color': 'red'}, {'second_color': 'green', 'main_color': 'red'}, {'main_color': 'red'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to check if a specific key's value exists in a list of dictionaries as shown below:

```py
a = [
    {'main_color': 'red', 'second_color':'blue'},
    {'main_color': 'yellow', 'second_color':'green'},
    {'main_color': 'yellow', 'second_color':'blue'}
]

# The 1st way
print(any(dict['main_color'] == 'red' for dict in a)) # True
print(any(dict['main_color'] == 'green' for dict in a)) # False

# The 2nd way
print(any('red' == dict['main_color'] for dict in a)) # True
print(any('green' == dict['main_color'] for dict in a)) # False
```

In addition, this code below can check if a value exists in a list of dictionaries:

```py
print(any('red' in dict.values() for dict in a)) # True
print(any('green' in dict.values() for dict in a)) # True
print(any('black' in dict.values() for dict in a)) # False
```

Answer (score 0):

Following works out for me.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    a = [{ 'main_color': 'red', 'second_color':'blue'},
    { 'main_color': 'yellow', 'second_color':'green'},
    { 'main_color': 'yellow', 'second_color':'blue'}]

    found_event = next(
            filter(
                lambda x: x['main_color'] == 'red',
                a
            ),
      #return this dict when not found
            dict(
                name='red',
                value='{}'
            )
        )

    if found_event:
        print(found_event)

    $python  /tmp/x
    {'main_color': 'red', 'second_color': 'blue'}
```