# Ansible check if key/value pair exists in list of dictionaries

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to check if a certain key/value pair exists in a list of dictionaries in Ansible.

I found this question, however I am not sure if the syntax differs from python to ansible (I have never seen an if statement in ansible!)
[Check if value already exists within list of dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897499/check-if-value-already-exists-within-list-of-dictionaries)

I have already tried the when condition:

```
  when: '"value" not in list'
```

however I have not had any luck with that.

For example, list looks something like:

```
list: [
   {
   "key1" : "value1",
   "key2" : "value2",
   "key3" : "value3"
   },
   {
   "key1" : "value4",
   "key2" : "value5",
   "key3" : "value6"
   },
   and so on
```

And I am trying to find out, for example, whether the pair `"key2":"value5"` exists within any of the dictionaries in the list. Hopefully there is a way to do this that just gives true if the pair exists, false if not?

Any tips would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here you go:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    list_of_dicts: [
     {
     "key1" : "value1",
     "key2" : "value2",
     "key3" : "value3"
     },
     {
     "key1" : "value4",
     "key2" : "value5",
     "key3" : "value3"
     }]
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: found
      when: list_of_dicts | selectattr(search_key,'equalto',search_val) | list | count > 0
      vars:
        search_key: key3
        search_val: value3
```

Comment: [equalto](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#equalto) is available since Jinja2 2.8, so I guess there's a bit of package chaos on your system. Check pip/system packages, ensure that Ansible uses Jinja2>=2.8.

Comment: It's working now, thanks! I suppose the jinja upgrade was recent and the server just needed a restart. Thanks for your help.

Comment: How can I get the index of dictionary in which that pair exists?