# How do I introduce values on a dict based on a condition met in nested dicts?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am trying to export some data from the following json: http://app.parlamento.pt/webutils/docs/doc.txt?path=6148523063446f764c324679626d56304c3239775a57356b595852684c3052685a47397a51574a6c636e52766379394a626d6c6a6157463061585a686379394a53556b6c4d6a424d5a57647063327868644856795953394a626d6c6a6157463061585a6863306c4a53563971633239754c6e523464413d3d&fich=IniciativasIII_json.txt&Inline=true.

Speciffically, whenever `iniDescTipo == "Proposta de Lei"`, I am looking for `iniNr`, `dataInicioleg` and `dataFimleg`. Also, I'm looking for `dataFase` when `fase == "Anúncio"`, and, whenever there's a dictionary within `iniEvntos` with `fase == "Decreto (Publicação)"`, I want an output of 1 in every row of the output file, and 0 otherwise. The intended output should look like this:

```
Title  Number InicioLeg FimLeg DataAnuncio Aprovado
  a      12      1991    1995     1992         1
  b      32      1991    1995     1991         1
  c      14      1991    1995     1991         0
```

My problem is the binary variable. As of now, my code is as follows:

```
r = requests.get('http://app.parlamento.pt/webutils/docs/doc.txt?path=6148523063446f764c324679626d56304c3239775a57356b595852684c3052685a47397a51574a6c636e52766379394a626d6c6a6157463061585a686379394a53556b6c4d6a424d5a57647063327868644856795953394a626d6c6a6157463061585a6863306c4a53563971633239754c6e523464413d3d&fich=IniciativasIII_json.txt&Inline=true')
r.raise_for_status()
data = r.json()

inis = data['ArrayOfPt_gov_ar_objectos_iniciativas_DetalhePesquisaIniciativasOut']['pt_gov_ar_objectos_iniciativas_DetalhePesquisaIniciativasOut']

for j in inis:
    if j['iniDescTipo'] == "Proposta de Lei":   
        for i in j['iniEventos']['pt_gov_ar_objectos_iniciativas_EventosOut']:
            if any("Decreto (Publicação)"):
                try:
                    pl.update({j['iniTitulo']: [j['iniTitulo'], j['iniNr'], j['dataInicioleg'],  j['dataFimleg'], j['iniEventos']['pt_gov_ar_objectos_iniciativas_EventosOut'][0]['dataFase'], "1"]})
                except KeyError:
                    pl.update({j['iniTitulo']: [j['iniTitulo'], j['iniNr'], j['dataInicioleg'],  j['dataFimleg'], j['iniEventos']['pt_gov_ar_objectos_iniciativas_EventosOut']['dataFase'], "0"]})      
    else:
        pass
```

I don't believe I've used the `if any` properly, hence the struggle with this last vavriable. I've tried some tips from [Check if value already exists within list of dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897499/check-if-value-already-exists-within-list-of-dictionaries), [Loop through all nested dictionary values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10756427/loop-through-all-nested-dictionary-values) and [Check if value already exists within list of dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897499/check-if-value-already-exists-within-list-of-dictionaries), but with no success. Can anyone point me to my mistake and, perhaps, suggest me a way to get all of the 5 variables?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I really got the problem but here we go:

First of all I would recommend you to avoid using variable names like `j` and `i`; it's easier to understand what the code is doing if variable names are descriptive of what they hold.

Indeed you are using `any()` the wrong way. `any()` receives an iterable an returns `True` if at least one element in that iterable is `True` and `False` otherwise.

One small change in what you already have to make it work could be replacing the second for loop for the following:

```
for j in inis:
    if j['iniDescTipo'] == "Proposta de Lei":
        i = j['iniEventos']['pt_gov_ar_objectos_iniciativas_EventosOut']
        if any(map(lambda elem: elem["fase"] == "Decreto (Publicação)", i):
            try:
                pl.update({j['iniTitulo']: [j['iniTitulo'], j['iniNr'], j['dataInicioleg'],  j['dataFimleg'], j['iniEventos']['pt_gov_ar_objectos_iniciativas_EventosOut'][0]['dataFase'], "1"]})
            except KeyError:
                pl.update({j['iniTitulo']: [j['iniTitulo'], j['iniNr'], j['dataInicioleg'],  j['dataFimleg'], j['iniEventos']['pt_gov_ar_objectos_iniciativas_EventosOut']['dataFase'], "0"]})      
    else:
        pass
```

This way, you are transforming your array `i` in a list of booleans which are `True` if the element has a `fase == "Decreto (Publicacao)"` and `False` otherwise; which is the input `any()` needs.

Regarding the `try: except:` part of the code, I'm pretty sure it could be better but, without too much knowledge of what these objects contain it's hard to recommend a better solution.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. It didn't really solve my problem, because i can't relate the ````any()```` function with the output. I should've explained my intentions better. But it gave me an idea. Can you tell me how can i introduce some variation of this ````any()```` function as a replacement for the 1 and 0 outputs? My problem would be solved if I could get "True" and "False" in the ````pl.update````, conditional on the existence of that key's value.

Comment: Ok, so the idea would be to put a `"1"` if the result of `any()` was `True` and `"0"` otherwise? If that's the case, then you could switch the `try:` for the `if` conditional, and the `except` for the `else`. That way, in every case where `any() == True` you will set `"1"` and in any other case you will set `"0"`. Sorry if I'm still not getting the objective.