# compare value in a list of multiple dictionaries and avoid duplicate inserts - python

Tags: python, python-3.x

compare multiple list of dicts and avoid duplicates
Requirement need to insert data only if readid doesn't exist in payload

```
old_data= [
    {
      "abc": "205",
      "xyz": "11.38",
      "ReadId": "120"
    },
    {
     "abc": "201",
      "xyz": "11.38",
      "ReadId": "121"
    },
    {
      "abc": "109",
      "xyz": "11.38",
      "ReadId": "122"

    }
  ]

payload= [
      {
        "reading_id": 120,
        "abc": 205
      },
      {
        "reading_id": 121,
        "abc": 199
      },
      {
        "reading_id": 123,
        "abcl": 128
      }
    ]
```

here, is the code I tried but didn't find luck

```
for d in payload:
   for dt in old_data:
      if 'ReadId' in data:
          if data['ReadId'] != payload['reading_id']:     
                  insertGluco(d['reading_id'])
```

any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: use ```set``` to find the difference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if value already exists within list of dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897499/check-if-value-already-exists-within-list-of-dictionaries)

Comment: there it's checking in a single dict, here I need to check in multiple dicts @DavidDr90

Comment: Is it an issue that you can't use that method on each dict, since they're already in a list? Similar to
 `for x in list_of_dicts: `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just modify your code slightly to use a set. It keeps all the read IDs of the old data and only inserts the payload dict if the read id is not present in the set.

A `set` stores unique values.

```
def insert(payload, old_data):
    read_ids = set(d.get("ReadId") for d in old_data)
    for igdata in payload:
        if igdata['reading_id'] not in read_ids:
            insertGluco(igdata['reading_id'], str(igdata['bgmmol']), str(igdata['bgmgdl']))
```

Comment: ya this looks fine, but how do I check whether key ReadId exists or not becoz every object in old_data may not have key ReadId.

Comment: You can replace d["ReadId"] with d.get("ReadId") then. This will use a None as default if the key is not present.
I've editted the answer.