# Find a value in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following list:

```
 {

   "id":1,
   "name":"John",
   "status":2,
   "custom_attributes":[
      {
         "attribute_code":"address",
         "value":"st"
      },
      {
         "attribute_code":"city",
         "value":"st"
      },
      {
         "attribute_code":"job",
         "value":"test"
      }]
}
```

I need to get the `value` from the `attribute_code` that is equal `city`

I've tried this code:

```
if list["custom_attributes"]["attribute_code"] == "city" in list:
     var = list["value"]
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

What i'm doing wrong here? I've read this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653516/python-list-of-dictionaries-search) and this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897499/check-if-value-already-exists-within-list-of-dictionaries) but din't understood how to access each value.

Comment: That's not a list.

Comment: I've used a `json.loads`, this is not a list?

Comment: No, it's a dictionary.

Comment: I'll though this was a list of dictionaries because have dictionaries within it. But ok, I'll try to find a reference to understand the difference between them.

Comment: You have a dictionary - let's call it **D**. You can access keys in a dictionary directly. You cannot access values in a dictionary directly. D['custom_attributes'] is a list of dictionaries. Each element in that list is a dictionary. You can use the dictionary built-in function *items()* to work through each of those dictionaries to try to find what you're looking for

Comment: @DarkKnight Thanks, now I understood!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution, using `next()`:

```py
dct = {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John",
    "status": 2,
    "custom_attributes": [
        {"attribute_code": "address", "value": "st"},
        {"attribute_code": "city", "value": "st"},
        {"attribute_code": "job", "value": "test"},
    ],
}

val = next(d["value"] for d in dct["custom_attributes"] if d["attribute_code"] == "city")
print(val)
```

Prints:

```
st
```

Answer (score 2):

Your data is a `dict` not a `list`.
You need to scan the attributes according the criteria you mentioned.
See below:

```
data = {

    "id": 1,
    "name": "John",
    "status": 2,
    "custom_attributes": [
        {
            "attribute_code": "address",
            "value": "st"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "city",
            "value": "st"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "job",
            "value": "test"
        }]
}

for attr in data['custom_attributes']:
    if attr['attribute_code'] == 'city':
        print(attr['value'])
        break
```

output

```
st
```